# Zend Framework DbTable insert() inserting records twice

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have a controller action as follows

```
 public function reportcommentAction() {
    $comment_id = $this->getRequest()->comment_id;

    $blockedCommentTable = new Application_Model_DbTable_BlockedComments();
    $blockedCommentTable->blockComment($comment_id, $this->user_id);

}
```

which makes a call to the blockComment() dbTable model which looks like this

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_BlockedComments extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

protected $_name = 'blocked_comments';

public function blockComment($comment_id, $blocked_by) {

    if (!empty($comment_id) && !empty($blocked_by)) {
        $data = array(
            'comment_id' => $comment_id,
            'blocked_by' => $blocked_by
        );

        $this->insert($data);
        exit;
    } 

}
```

For some reason, I need that exit; at the end. Without it I get 2 records inserted instead of just the one as expected.

I have 3 fields in the blocked_comments table, i.e. id, comment_id and blocked by. With the exit statement in place I get a record with values 1, 21, 1 as expected. Without the exit statement I get an extra record with values 2, 0, 1 for some reason.

I have the same code ( without the superfluous exit) working in other parts of my code and I have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: Should be easy enough to look into if you have something like xdebug. You're sure the method isn't getting called twice?

Comment: @JohnP It sure looks like it is being called twice but I cannot see how. I will see if I can step through it with xdebug.

Comment: I have run the project with the debugger on and the reportcommentAction is being called twice. The first time it is being called correctly and the Request_Uri reports /us/account/report-comment/21 where 21 is the comment_id parameter. The second time round the Request_Uri reports /us/account/report-comment/default.appcache?v=1 which means nothing to me.

Comment: Not intentionally. I don't know if the Zend Framework turns cacheing on automatically somewhere, but I have not so by design.

Comment: Check whether you've added a manifest attribute to your HTML tag right at the top. If so, remove it.

Comment: @JohnP Thanks - that has resolved it. I was experimenting with the 320 and up CSS framework, and it is based on HTML5 boilerplate which added the manifest attribute to the HTML tag. I have been working on this project for some time and this issue did not surface until now. I am not sure if this is a bug or a problem with my code that is preventing me from using the HTML5 application cache.

Comment: The problem is likely with your routing. I think it may have be looking for the file, which is either not there or on a different path, and the normal zend routing got activated rather than serving the static file. I've added this as an answer in case anyone else comes across the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The second time round the Request_Uri reports /us/account/report-comment/default.appcache?v=1
```

Remove the `manifest` attribute in the main HTML tag (right at the top) to get rid of the second call. Zend's application routing seems to be kicking in instead of serving the static file. This could be because the file does not exist or might exist on a different path.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The reason why `->insert` was called twice was because of these:

```
public function saveAction()
{   ... 
    $result = $this->_bookModel->saveBook($data);
    if ($result) {
        $this->view->form = $form->reset();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer('index');  
    }
```

I have replaced

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer('index');
```

with

```
return $this->_helper->redirector('index');
```

and it worked perfect.